# Add list of values to a blob field in firebird using Python

Tags: python, blob, firebird

I have a list of items which I like to store in my firebird database.
Thus far I made the following code

```
    Sens=278.3
    DSens=1.2
    Fc10=3.8
    Bw10=60.0
    Fc20=4.2
    Bw20=90.0

    ResultArray = (Sens,DSens,Fc10,Bw10,Fc20,Bw20,t6,t20,Nel,Nsub)
    con = fdb.connect(dsn="192.168.0.2:/database/us-database/usdb.gdb",  user="sysdba", password="#########")
    cur = con.cursor()
    InsertStatement="insert into Tosh_Probe (TestResults ) Values (?)"
    cur.execute(InsertStatement, (ResultArray,))                           
    con.commit()
```

In here the TestResult field is blob field in my database.

This gives a TypeError (???)
What is the correct syntax to store these values into a blob

An other option I tried is to write the list of items into a StringIO, and store that in the database. Now a new entry is made in the database but no data is added to the blob field
Here is the code for adding the fields to the StringIO

```
    ResultArray = StringIO.StringIO()
    ResultArray.write = Sens
    ResultArray.write = DSens   
    #ResultArray.close #tried with and without this line but with the same result
```

Comment: Are you using fdb or another driver? You are passing a tuple as the value which is not an acceptable value for a blob. You need to convert it to a single value (eg as a string, or a stream). AFAIK `StringIO` should work, but I haven't done anything with python for a while.

Comment: Yes I'm using the fdb driver. I understand that my list won't work that's why I tried the SrtingIO but somehow the blobfields remains empty.

Comment: For now I "solved" it by parsing my values to a comma separated string and add that to the blob field, but somehow that is not satisfying at all, since I just want to parse my values to a binairy stream in a binary format  and add that that to to the blob field. I hope some of you can guide me in the right direction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tested this with Python 3.5.1 and FDB 1.6. The following variants of writing all work (into a `blob sub_type text`):

```
import fdb
import io

con = fdb.connect(dsn='localhost:testdatabase', user='sysdba', password='masterkey')

cur = con.cursor()
statement = "insert into blob_test2 (text_blob) values (?)"
cur.execute(statement, ("test blob as string",))
cur.execute(statement, (io.StringIO("test blob as StringIO"),))
streamwrites = io.StringIO()
streamwrites.write("streamed write1,")
streamwrites.write("streamed write2,")
streamwrites.seek(0)
cur.execute(statement, (streamwrites,))

con.commit()

con.close()
```

The major differences with your code in the case of the the writes to `StringIO` are:

1. Use of `write(...)` instead of `write = ...`
2. Use of `seek(0)` to position the stream at the start, otherwise you read nothing, as the stream is positioned after the last write.

I haven't tried binary IO, but I expect that to work in a similar fashion.